# Can two RAMs with different frequencies (DDR4 Sodimm) be used together in Laptop?

Tags: ddr3

Can two RAMs with different frequencies (but same type: DDR4 Sodimm) be used together in Laptop? (eg: 2400mz with 2666mz)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can mix ram speeds, but it's not recommended. Effective speed of the rams will be matching the slowest ram speed. There can be performance issues with different timings. Normally you want to put exactly the same ram sticks to your computer.